# Calling SOAP webservices results in java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present while opening stream

Tags: soap

I am trying to call a SOAP webservices using a Java code. My code is below:

```
// username and password.
final String username = "admin";
        final String password = "admin";
        Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        username,
                        password.toCharArray());
            }
        });
        //URL of the endpoint
        URL url = new URL("https://IP:9443/services/ExecutionManagerAdminService?wsdl");
        // creating QName 
        QName qname = new QName("http://admin.manager.execution.event.carbon.wso2.org", "ExecutionManagerAdminServiceHttpsSoap11Endpoint");
        // creating service
        Service service = Service.create(url, qname);

        ExecutionManagerAdminServicePortType adminService = service.getPort(ExecutionManagerAdminServicePortType.class);
         Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) adminService).getRequestContext();
         requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, url.toString());
         // Setting username and Password 
         requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, username);
         requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, password);
         Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
         headers.put("Timeout", Collections.singletonList("10000"));
         requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
        // Results
        System.out.println(adminService.getAllDomains());
```

Result:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://IP:9443/services/ExecutionManagerAdminService?wsdl
```

But same webservice if i invoke using SOAP UI by setting request //properties to set username and password it works well.

Comment: // Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://IP:9443/services/ExecutionManagerAdminService?wsdl. It failed with: 
         Got java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present while opening stream from https://IP:9443/services/ExecutionManagerAdminService?wsdl.
         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: //Caused by: java.io.IOException: Got java.security.cert.CertificateException: //No subject alternative names present while opening stream from https://IP:9443/services/ExecutionManagerAdminService?wsdl
         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(Unknown Source)
         at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(Unknown Source)
         ... 9 more

Comment: //  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
         at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
         at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
         at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
 
        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
         at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(Unknown Source)
         at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please don't keep putting // on the front of your comments. If you want to have them appear in code font then you should use backticks ` to surround text.